# I removed the module from my site and now I'm getting an entity type error

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have an issue where I removed the paragraphs and bootstrap_paragraphs modules from my site and now I am unable to access the admin or the site. It is saying that the paragraphs entity type doesn't exist is the entity types manager.  Is there a way using drush that I can add this entity type or just remove all references to it to get the site back up?

[image]

Comment: The error happens during bootstrap while rebuilding the views data structure. Assuming you did a clean uninstall the problem is probably custom code/config depending on paragraphs. See for example the 7th line of the backtrace.

Comment: And what happens when you put the module back?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore the site using drush and re-installing the modules. 
I did a drush cache-rebuild
then reinstalled the modules via drush dl and drush en and it restored the site.